# creating this matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Given

```
A=[a_1 a_2 a_3 ... a_n]
```

How to make this?

```
[a1 ... a100]
[a2 ... a101]
...
[an-100+1 ... an]
```

I want to not use for-loop here since I want to speed it up.
Thank you.

Comment: It seems you are only dealing with reshaping here, so why not do `reshape(A,100,[]).'`?

Comment: @Divakar it is not reshaping in fact. There are overlapping between first and second row.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
n = numel(A);
m = 100;
I = bsxfun(@plus, 1:m, (0:n-m).');
B = A(I);
```

As a sidenote: The `for` loop doesn't perform *that* bad:

```
B = zeros(n-m+1, m);
for i = 1:size(B)
    B(i,:) = A(i:i+m-1);
end
```

As far as my testing goes, it is slower only by a factor of 4 and this calculation should hardly be a bottleneck in your program anyway.